# How can I find out where an environment variable (like PATH) was set?

Tags: linux, bash, path, environment-variables

I have a xterm with the bash shell in linux. When I `echo $PATH`, it is showing a directory and I want to know who put this directory in the `PATH`. How can I find out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your login shell is bash, you could start looking in the following files: `/etc/profile`, `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`. If you invoke bash from another shell, then you might need to check what variables the other shell sets.

Answer (score 1):

You probably cannot discover who, but you can find out which file is setting that.  Look a the Bash documentation for the startup files.  There are several that bash processes on startup to set $PATH and the other environment variables.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Answer (score 0):

**This answer assumes your login shell is bash.**

---

I use an alias that simulates the opening of a login shell and outputs verbose logs to stdout.

Depending on how you configure your dotfiles, you might want to choose something other than `~/.bashrc`, however, for my purposes, this works because `~/.bashrc` is where I source all of my various configuration files and exports.

```bsh
alias simlogin='PS4='\''+~/.bashrc> '\'' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xl 7>&2'
```

**Note** that after you run this command, your current shell will output a trace on every subsequent prompt and command, so you'll probably want to exit the shell after you find what you need.

[There's a good answer here](https://serverfault.com/a/579078/52777) that can help you improve this debugging experience by redirecting the debug log output to a file (or other location).

Answer (score -1):

Also you could take a look to the file /etc/environment

Comment: It isn't clear how this answers the question.